# jQuery css() not in working in conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a simple parallax scroller that scales images to the screen width, sets a scrolling wrapper that is set to the scaled height of all the images, and looks at the scrollTop value to set top position of the images using jQuery's css(). Here is the main function:

```
function positionSlides() {
    sT = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('div.slide img').each(function(){
        wp = $(this).attr('data-waypoint');
        if(sT >= wp){
            $(this).css({'top' : wp, 'border' : '1px solid red'});
            //console.log(sT + ':sT, ' + wp + ':wp');
        }
        else{
            $(this).css({'top' : ((wp-sT)/4)+sT, 'border' : '1px solid blue'});
        }
    });
}
```

The setting of the border colors is there to test which conditional statement is passing.

positionSlides() is called on scroll via

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    positionSlides();
});
```

My problem is when `sT >= wp`, the css property 'top' is not set to the value of `wp`. It is set to what seems to be the last value passed by the else statement, which is some value slightly less than `wp`. But at the same time, `'border' : '1px solid red'` is set correctly via the same if statement.

Why is the 'top' property not set in the if part of the statement?

Comment: `$(window).scroll( positionSlides )` is a bit faster on execution

Comment: what exactly does wp contain in that case? in the else it is numeric, in the if it is a string (all attributes are strings).

Comment: Don't you need to also append `px` to the css `top` property (unless it's 0)

Comment: AFAIK, `.css()` is an instant function. That should happen unless the values of `sT` and `wp` are incorrect. Can you show those values?

Comment: Besides the missing `px` mentioned by steveax, you also need `position: absolute` (or `relative`, or `fixed`) to be able to use `top`.

Comment: @Kevin B, `wp` is the value of a data-waypoint attribute set by another function. It is capable of setting the top prop. in the else statement but not the if part.

@Alexander, I logged the values of `sT` and `wp` to the console and they are correct. The fact that the border colors change correctly shows the conditional statement working. The main issue is that the 'top' property is not being set in the if part of the statement.

Comment: @andypants Since both parts of the statement are identical other than performing operations on `wp`,the value/type of `wp` must be the reason it isn't working. In the first part, `wp` is a string, in the second part you converted it to a number by performing numeric opterations on a number-like string. Try converting the string in the first part to a numeric value.

Comment: @andypants, It's well-known that `.css()` reacts differently depending you pass a number or a string. You can quickly check this by using `'top' : +wp` instead

Comment: @Kevin B, you sir are correct! I was assuming that wp was an integer as it was working with the other css(). I was unaware that performing arithmetic on a string would automatically convert it to an integer. Please add this as an answer as it is correct. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you work with `wp` where it isn't working it is a string. The second time, it is an integer or float when you do `wp-sT`. if you convert the first version to a numeric value it will work.

```
var wp = parseInt($(this).attr('data-waypoint'),10);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that somehow `wp` isn't getting loaded with the expected value - not much room for anything else to go wrong here.

Are you sure wp is pulling the value you expect? How is the element's `data-waypoint` attribute being set - maybe that's the culprit?

If not, can you give us example values of what you expect top to be set to, and what it actually gets set to?

Comment: Hence my logging the values to the console. `wp` sets correctly and gets pulled via `attr()` correctly. What happens is that the value of the top attribute is not set to the value of `wp` after scrolling past that waypoint, the if part `sT >= wp`.

Comment: Any way you can stick this in a fiddle for us with some sample html? It's a lot easier to play with it than having you answer our dumb questions =)

Comment: Kevin B answered this in the comments on my question. Waiting for him to add his answer. Thanks Moose.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're firing this on every single scroll event. Which is a lot. Check out [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/parallax/) on HTML5Rocks.com. It basically suggests using `requestAnimationFrame()` and checking the position each time instead of doing it on a scroll event.

In your case, you could just change your code to

```
requestAnimationFrame(positionSlides);
```